# Task does not contain definition for Result

Tags: c#, auth0

I am getting an error on this function

```
private void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var auth0 = new Auth0Client("sample.auth0.com", "iRyFSIfQaeG4KXKd36D3CEPxkPyJ0Ekk");

    auth0.LoginAsync(new WindowWrapper(new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle))
        .ContinueWith(
            t => { this.textBox1.Text = t.Result.Profile.ToString(); },
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
}
```

Error Message:

> Task does not contain a definition for result and no extension method
>   accepting Result accepting first argument of type task could be found.

The Error is thrown on the line `t.Result.Profile.ToString()`

I am fairly new to Task Concept.Please help!

Comment: `Task` doesn't have a `Result` property.  Only `Task<TResult>` as one.  It's like the difference between a `void` method and one that has a return type.  Basically it means that `LoginAsync` is returning `Task` which is the asynchronous version of `void`.

Comment: Unless you work with an older .Net version use async / await for this. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx

Comment: I hope that is not your real token you are showing there...